# Test action outputs length

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In my Logic App workflow, I'm trying to evaluate a condition for the previous action outputs array.

My condition expression

```
@less(action('Get_items').outputs.length, 1)
```

results in error

> action 'Item_found' completed with status 'Failed' and code 'BadRequest'.

The same happens for

```
@greater(action('Get_items').outputs.length, 1)
```

as well as

```
@empty(action('Get_items').outputs)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

Background: The `action('Get_items')` is query retrieving items from a SPO site list using a Filter Query.
The action succeeds but the App Run Trace doesn't show any details on the outputs, in this case the expected empty array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to achieve the desired condition evaluation by correctly accessing the array the same way a `for-each` action does:

```
@empty(body('Get_items')['value'])
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/mt643789.aspx) doesn't give a hint on this.

Comment: This would be the best way of doing it. Note that `body('Get_items') == outputs('Get_items').body == action('Get_items').outputs.body`.

Comment: I tried all variations you mentioned but favored brevity. It seems you also know about SharePoint Online - do you know if it is possible to CRUD list items from Azure Biztalk Services? I can't figure out [how I can make the generic WCF Connector work with SPO claim based authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38738344/205233).

Comment: BizTalk APIs are not available with the latest version of Logic Apps. You may want to take a look at Enterprise Integration Pack: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-enterprise-integration-overview/

Comment: I already read that article - my goal is rather to create a Biztalk Service-only solution instead of a Logic App solution. But from what I've seen, it seems MS looks into blending it all together with WABS components only being a dedicated Action for complex transformation and routing tasks but without a full set of connectors.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted solution was not working for me for CDS entities, so I have solved it by using such condition:

```
@length(body('Get_items')['value'])
```

If I understand correctly it is converting array to string and empty array is converted to `[]`, so you just have to check if the output of query is more than 2, then it means `Get_Items` is not empty.